# Should i use schema restrictions or user restrictions?

Tags: sql-server

is it possible to grant premission's for a role to only select,insert in a database schema or do i have to do it for every table individualy

```
    CREATE ROLE role1
    GO
    GRANT INSERT,SELECT ON [database1].[schema1] TO role1
    GO
```

P.s can i create a role without assigning nobody to that role , because as i read in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx 
it say's that when u create a role and don't assign nobody the user with which u have created the role will be assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Create a role with the required DML permissions to a schema, like you've scripted above. Then you will need to assign users to the new role if you want to give them this access. Like this:

```
ALTER ROLE [role1] ADD MEMBER [user1]
GO
```

I think you might be getting this confused with [ownership chaining](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx). I don't think you want to do this.

Comment: okey thank's, but the query which i showed above isn't working it won't recognize the databaze nor the schema so could u tell me how would the correct format of the query to create a role with some permissions on a specific database